# My Python code return different answers when it runs and when it is in step-by-step debugging

Tags: python, debugging, bignum

---

I try to write some code on **Python2.7**, which will able to implement a bignum arithmetic, using linear lists. I know, this is useless in Python, but it's my homework in collage. I write some working pieces of code, but problem is in **dividing**. I'm sure that function works, but when I run code to test it, I just get wrong answer (in some cases). But if I execute code step-by-step, it works correctly.

I'm using linux, but I tested my code on my friend's windows computer, and I got the same problem. I wrote code in **Eclipse with PyDev**, if it is matter.

My code on Ideone: [**Code**](http://ideone.com/wLbwF)

If lines in console output are the same - output is correct. On Ideone output is incorrect too. But if you put a breakpoint on line 383 and then go in the **_simple_div** method, answer will be correct

I hope you help me to find a reason of this.
P.S. Sorry for ugly code.

Comment: you should check http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This code is too long, try and give a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) :)

Comment: It's not so easy, I can say, that all functions (I think that _simple_div too) are correct, especially then it runs step-by step. Can I ask you only to test my code using debugger and simply run it and say me results? Just put a breakpoint on line 383 and then go in the _simple_div method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I run your code, I get

```
~/coding:$ python divbug2.py 
1-1
10
```

That `-1` doesn't look right.  Is there a `-1` being inserted somewhere in the division?  First thing to try is to search for `-1` in that function, which gives

```
        i-=1
        res._addFirst(i)
        if i==-1: i=0
```

.. and that looks strange, because if `i == -1`, then you've just added it to `res`.  Maybe we should check first, i.e.

```
        i-=1
        if i==-1: i=0
        res._addFirst(i)
```

Swapping those two lines produces

```
~/coding:$ python divbug2.py 
10
10
```

And then -- after writing a real `.copy()` method, because `copy.deepcopy` was *really* slow and even using PyPy I got bored waiting for things to finish:

```
>>>> all(int(str(LongNum(x)._simple_div(LongNum(y)))) == x/y for x in range(2000) for y in range(1, 2000))
True
```

I'm not sure why this was working for you when you did it step-by-step, but I'm a little surprised it worked at all.

Comment: Thanks! I'm paste `if i==-1: i=0`
 but it was a hack, hm, I'm blind man, I paste it in wrong place! Thanks very much! I'll do a real copy method.